# ¿Cómo calcular en R los segundos entre series de tiempo?

Tags: r, date

Tengo esta lista

```
# A tibble: 22,707 × 1
   clock   
   <chr>   
 1 00:12:00
 2 00:11:55
 3 00:11:31
 4 00:11:29
 5 00:11:13
 6 00:11:10
 7 00:11:02
 8 00:10:59
 9 00:10:50
10 00:10:47
# … with 22,697 more rows
```

Y me gustaría obtener otra columna con los segundos transcurridos entre una fila y la de abajo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer un poco más simple:

```
library(lubridate)

pbp_clock %>% 
  mutate(clock_t = parse_time(clock),
         sec_play = lag(clock_t) - clock_t,
         sec_play_int = as.numeric(sec_play))
```

Notas:

- Dispones de `parse_time()` que entiende perfectamente el formato `hh:mm:ss`
- Al convertir ya tienes un objeto `hms` que entiende ciertas reglas aritméticas, por ejemplo, la resta te devuelve ya el intervalo en la forma de un objeto `difftime`
- El `difftime` se puede representar de varias formas, pero si queremos los segundos, simplemente habrá que convertirlo a un numérico.
- Por cierto, esto: `lubridate::minute(clock)*60 + lubridate::second(clock)`,  esto funciona pero conceptualmente está mal, por que los dos valores están retornando lo mismo con distintas unidades, es decir 1:05 se puede descomponer en 1 minuto o 65 segundos.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Patricio

Answer (score 2):

Quizás he dado mucha vuelta pero este es el código con lo que lo he logrado finalmente

```
pbp_clock <- pbp_clock %>% 
  select(clock) %>% 
  mutate(clock = lubridate::parse_date_time(clock, lubridate::ms(clock)),
         seconds = lubridate::minute(clock)*60 + lubridate::second(clock),
         sec_play = lag(seconds)- seconds)
```

y este es el tibble resultante

```
# A tibble: 22,707 × 3
   clock               seconds sec_play
   <dttm>                <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 0000-01-01 00:12:00     720       NA
 2 0000-01-01 00:11:55     715        5
 3 0000-01-01 00:11:31     691       24
 4 0000-01-01 00:11:29     689        2
 5 0000-01-01 00:11:13     673       16
 6 0000-01-01 00:11:10     670        3
 7 0000-01-01 00:11:02     662        8
 8 0000-01-01 00:10:59     659        3
 9 0000-01-01 00:10:50     650        9
10 0000-01-01 00:10:47     647        3
# … with 22,697 more rows
```

gracias